# Browser's "Previous" button location change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url

Is there a way to change where "previous" button in browser goes?

The problem is the following:

1. User enters page
2. User clicks thumbnail image
3. Large image appears in popup window (lightbox) and **URL CHANGES** from http://example.com/ to http://example.com/this-image-link/
4. I click "Previous" button in browser and **URL CHANGES** from http://example.com/this-image-link/ to http://example.com/ but POPUP doesn't disappear (and page doesn't refresh).

How would I make it go back to http://example.com/ and close my popup after clicking "Back" in browser?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. And the plugin that changes the URL should be responsible for handling the state-change back - please show us its code.

Comment: @Bergi there is no code. Only `window.history.pushState({}, title, permalink);` and I want an element (popup) to disappear upon clicking "back" in browser. So, let's say I want `.container` to disappear when you click "back" and appear when you click "forward".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do some reading on manipulating the browser's history. Those links will certainly give you a good intro:

[History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

[MDN Manipulating the Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/)

This JS Library should also help you, if you want to overcome cross-browser limitations and evade JQuery, as suggested above.

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery Hashchange plugin. Registers the hash change event for all browsers.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: In the OPs question there is no hash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I'll manage to make it work with both answers to this question :)